# Im getting an error message in a loop

Tags: java

I have created a class called Employee and i have declared the variables. Now i want to create a function "getValue();" inside the loop, but im getting an error "The method getValues() is undefined for the type Employee". This is my code.

```
//main class
public class Employee {

    //variable declaration

    private String EName, EDesig; 
    private double BSal=0.0, HA=0.0, GSal=0.0;
    private int EmpNo;

    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Number of Employees");
        int number = input.nextInt();

        int[] N = new int[4];          //instantiate array
        int i;

        for(i=0; i<number; i++) {
            getValues();
            CalculateSalary();
            DisplayValues();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think the error means?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. **Read it.**

Comment: Im getting an error message at "getValues(); CalculateSalary(); DisplayValues();... the message says the "The method getValues() is undefined for the type Employee"

Comment: What do you think the error means?

Comment: Not that I'm being pedantic or anything but... you state you want to create a function "getValue", but your code calls getValues plural.

Comment: `Now i want to create a function "getValue();" inside the loop`       you are going in a wrong way

Comment: You are calling the function `getValues()` but you haven't declared it anywhere. At least, not anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: How would i need to declared it. Would i need to declared inside the class Employee e.g private string, private double, private int....

Comment: It depends on the usage. getValues() to me looks like it would be an instance-based method (each Employee has its own values?) so its probably not gonna be static. As for private vs public and return type, I suggest you decide what getValues() should do and do some internet research then

Comment: How you declare it depends on what you want it to do and how you want other code to interact with it. You can't just type `getValue()` and have it automatically declared. Read up here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score 0):

Where is your method getValue()? Show us the codes. All of it.
Is it static or non-static? Is it inside the same class? 
If it's static and inside the same class, you can call it like that, but if it's in another class, you have to type the name of that class too, and the name of the method separated by a dot. If it's non-static, you have to make an object out of the class in which the method is in first.

This is how you make an object:
(CLASS NAME)(NAME OF OBJECT) = new (CONSTRUCTOR's NAME)();
The constructor's name is the same as the class name.

Then when you call the method, you just put the name of object, and the method name, separated by a dot. Hope this helps. Also, please post the whole code, so we call see what else is wrong with the rest of the codes.

Comment: You only posted part of the code. We can't help if you don't post the whole code. Look at the code yourself. Where is your getValue() method? It's not in the code. You're just calling it.